# How do I keep a list element held on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a quiz app using react. I fetch 5 quiz blocks from api and render them all together in the page. I want when I click on list ".answer" element to remain clicked. (for example to change color to blue and keep the color.. unless it's click again.then it should change to it's original format) At the moment I can display the id of each list item even thought the columns have the same id(which I don't know how to fix).

I would be nice if someone could explain the big picture. Maybe the approach is not right. I saw some quiz apps on youtube but they were different style.(they showed 1 question at a time and click next for the next one).
I want the user to click all 5 answers and then check them all together.

This is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Game() {
    const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);

    function shuffle(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
        return array;
    }

    const fetchQuiz = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(
            "https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions?limit=5"
        );
        const randomQuiz = await res.json();
        const updated = randomQuiz.map((item) => ({
            ...item,
            isHeld: false,
        }));

        const shuffledQuiz = updated.map((item) => {
            // Combine incorrect and correct answers into a single array
            const answers = [...item.incorrectAnswers, item.correctAnswer];
            // Shuffle the answers
            const shuffledAnswers = shuffle(answers);

            return { ...item, answers: shuffledAnswers };
        });

        setQuiz(shuffledQuiz);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchQuiz();
    }, []);

    const answerClicked = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
    };

    //generate list items//
    let block = quiz.map((item) => {
        const answerElements = item.answers.map((answer, index) => (
            <li
                key={index}
                className="answer"
                onClick={() => answerClicked(index)}
            >
                {answer}
            </li>
        ));

        return (
            <div key={item.id} className="quiz_block">
                <h1 className="quiz_question">{item.question}</h1>
                <ul className="quiz_answers">{answerElements}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="game_container">
                {block}

                <div className="footer">
                    <button>Check answers</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a state to store selected answer of each quiz

```
const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = React.useState({});

const answerClicked = (quizId, answerIndex) => {
    setUserAnswer((prev) => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            [quizId]: prev[quizId] === answerIndex ? null : answerIndex,
        };
    });
};

let block = quiz.map((item) => {
    const answerElements = item.answers.map((answer, index) => (
        <li
            key={index}
            className={`answer ${userAnswer[item.id] === index && 'selected'}`}
            onClick={() => answerClicked(item.id, index)}
        >
            {answer}
        </li>
    ));

    return (
        <div key={item.id} className="quiz_block">
            <h1 className="quiz_question">{item.question}</h1>
            <ul className="quiz_answers">{answerElements}</ul>
        </div>
    );
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lake-5yug16?file=/src/App.js:1292-1801)